# regular expression for is empty space

Tags: javascript, regex, expression, string

I'm suresomeone of you know how to do this easily, I am trying to validate my inputs that only allows numbers, characters and/or an empty space which mean nothing in a string `""`, so I have `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/` only missing that empty space in there. Seems I can't find the express for it, so I tried to create a variabel `var emptyStr = ""` and put it in there but don't really know how to write the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `*` rather than `+`.  `*` is 0 or more times. `+` is 1 or more times.

`/^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/`

Comment: this worked well for an empty string but it allows special characters now which I don't want from the begining

Comment: @nihulus This pattern does not allow special characters.  Mind posting a jsfiddle showing what you mean?

Comment: sorry it worked well, just somewhere else in the code was wrong, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[A-z0-9\s]*$/
```

The `\s` will also capture spaces